# Link to chat-room

Tags: support, chat

I'm a bit confused about the right-hand side-bar on site.
When do I get the "chat-room" links shown there and when not?

I *currenlty* see them on the meta-site only, but I can't remember if I've seen them on the main-page as well and when. Clarifications, please.

Edit: **Now** I see them on both sites, but I could have sworn the section was not there on the main site a minute ago ??? (Or am I just getting blind & crazy?)

[image: Currently PuzzlingMeta]

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it either! They seem to randomly pop up and disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those quirky, subtle distinctions on Stack Exchange sites.

`[meta.]puzzling.stackexchange.com/` is not the same as `[meta.]puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions`. "Visit Chat" section (usually?) shows under `/`, but not under `/questions`.

You can see this behavior for yourself: if you click on the site logo, it will link you to `/`, where Visit Chat will appear. If you then click on 'Questions', it will take you to `/questions`, where it (and the newsletter signup) will be replaced with favorite and related tags.

Comment: This can't be the whole explanation, though, since I don't see it on either right now.  `/` has a Newsletter sign-up that's not on `/questions`, but netiher has the chatroom links.  Strange.

Comment: W. Weird. I'm going to go with, "when the magic web design gremlins feel like it," then.

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes happens to me too, the *"X People Talking"* link is not always visible, but i don't know why.

If you want you can access to the chat from anywhere by clicking the Stack Exchange logo in the top left corner and then click "chat"

[image]